# kn320 not connecting to bluedio headphones

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, adapter

Bought kn320 to bridge the connection of jackaudio and bluetooth headphones. They are compatible as of characteristics. But the problem is that kn320 only blinks once with orange light upon powering on sequence. After that it doesn't blink orange even once. Orange light means "receiver connecting".

Answer (score 0):

It appears that to switch the mode of it you need to re-plug it into USB port.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcRzT.jpg